# How to clear EOFill/Fill?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ipad, cgcontext

I understand there is CGContextClearRect though that makes you clear everything inside the drawRect class. 
How do i select one CGContextRef and clear that instead?
for my case my code goes:

```
//Put clearing syntax here
if(dp.gPoints == nil || dp.gPoints->size() < 1)
    return;
CGContextBeginPath(g);
vector<CGPoint>::iterator k = dp.gPoints->begin();
CGContextMoveToPoint(g, (*k).x, (*k).y);
++k;
while(k != dp.gPoints->end()){
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(g, (*k).x, (*k).y);
    ++k;
}
vector<CGPoint>::reverse_iterator L = dp.dPoints->rbegin();
while(L != dp.doodlePoints->rend()){
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(g, (*L).x, (*L).y);
    ++L;
}
//CGContextAddLineToPoint(g, (*k).x, (*k).y);
CGContextSetFillColor(g, CGColorGetComponents([[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]));
CGContextEOFillPath(g);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace these two lines:

```
CGContextSetFillColor(g, CGColorGetComponents([[UIColor greenColor] CGColor]));
CGContextEOFillPath(g);
```

with these lines:

```
CGContextSaveGState(g);
CGContextEOClip(g);
CGContextClearRect(g, rect);
CGContextRestoreGState(g);
```

assuming `rect` was the argument passed to your `drawRect:` method.

Comment: i did try this before i asked the question, and it seemed to just go over the original green

Comment: thats not going to work as well... All it does it clips the image and loses everything behind the image. Not exactly transparent.

Comment: I am going to figure out a different way of doing this. Thanks for the help though